# Trying to open image with PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to open a file with PIL and tkinter. Im using this code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import *
intWidth=20
intHeight=5

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)



        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0,column=0)#pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)



        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, Departure, PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.config(bg='#FBC311')

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        for row in range(9):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
            Button(self,text="Button %d"%(row), bg = '#005ca0', fg = 'white', font = "Verdana 10", width = intWidth, height = intHeight).grid(row = row,column = 0,sticky = E+W)

        for c in range(9):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
            Button(self,text="Button %d"%(c), bg = '#005ca0', fg = 'white', font = "Verdana 10", width = intWidth, height = intHeight).grid(row = 5,column = c,sticky = E+W)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="Welkom bij NS", font='Verdana 50', fg='#005ca0', bg='#FBC311')
        label.grid(row=1,column=3,columnspan=3)

        path = "nslogo.png"
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
        panel = Label(self , image=img, bg = '#FBC311', width = 340)
        panel.photo = img
        panel.grid(column=4, row=2)


        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Actuele reistijden", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("Departure"),bg='#005ca0', fg='white',width=20,height=5)
        button1.grid(row=6, column=3,sticky='nsew')
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page Two", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageTwo"),bg='#005ca0', fg='white',width=20,height=5)
        button2.grid(row=6,column=5,sticky='nsew')

class Departure(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        for row in range(7):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
        for c in range(7):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Actuele vertrektijden", font='Verdana 50', fg='#005ca0', bg='#FBC311')
        label.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=5)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Start",command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"),bg='#005ca0', fg='white',width=20,height=5)
        button.grid(row=2,column=4)


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        for row in range(7):
            self.grid_rowconfigure(row, weight=1)
        for c in range(7):
            self.grid_columnconfigure(c, weight=1)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Storingen", font='Verdana 50', fg='#005ca0', bg='#FBC311')
        label.grid(row=0,column=2,columnspan=5)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"), bg='#005ca0', fg='white',width=20,height=5)
        button.grid(row=2,column=4)


app = SampleApp()

app.mainloop()
```

But im getting an error:

File "C:/Users/kevin/Desktop/HU/Programming/TICT-ViPROG-15/mini_project/test.py", line 59, in **init**
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

I have no idea why this is happening and was hoping someone coul help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a namespace conflict. Instead of doing...

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
```

Try doing:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from PIL import Image as PilImage
```

and then, in the line you're getting the error, you'll do:

```
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(PilImage.open(path))
```

I hope that helps. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused by the way that you import the `tkinter` module:

```
from PIL import Image,ImageTk
from tkinter import *
```

The second import will replace any existing names of variables, classes etc. with those contained in the `tkinter` module. It just so happens that there is an `Image` class defined in `tkinter` (that doesn't have an `open()` method), so it will replace the one that was already imported from `PIL`.

```
>> from tkinter import  *
>>> Image
<class 'tkinter.Image'>
```

This is a demonstration of why it is preferable not to use `import *`, although it is common to do so with Tkinter.

One way to fix this is to swap the order of your imports so that `PIL.Image` replaces `tkinter.Image`, but that now prevents you from using `tkinter.Image` if you had wanted to use both in the same namespace.

So, you can import using `as` to define your own name for items imported from the module:

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image as PILImage
```

and use `PILImage` instead of `Image` when you require a `PIL.Image`.